# NPM/Gulp relative paths

Tags: node.js, sass, npm, gulp

I have searched the google, but everytime I ask our uncle google about it, he responds with uninteresting data that I don't need.

The problem is:

I have basic knowledge of `gulp` and I want to compile a `scss` file using `gulp-sass`, everything is good until I started using `susy` instaled by bower.

I am including it using:

```
@import "../../bower_components/susy/sass/susy";
```

And it works.

The question is: can I do something with npm, gem, ruby, or gulp to not have to enter this massive relative path?

I want to type for example:

```
@import "susy";
@import "breakpoint";
@import "modular-scale";
```

Instead of:

```
@import "../../bower_components/susy/sass/susy";
@import "../../bower_components/breakpoint/breakpoint/breakpoint";
@import "../../bower_components/modular-scale/stylesheets/modular-scale";
```

I do not want to to use compass, but if it is only one way to do this, I will go for it.